# progress dialog for loading audio from internet on MediaPlayer obj

Tags: android, media-player, progressdialog

I want to play a MP3 stream from internet.

I wrote this code but i want showing a spinning progress dialog at preparing audio file.

Help me to make a progress dialog that starts before loading and closes after that.

Code is Here:

```
try {
    mp.setDataSource(AUDIO URL);
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();
}
catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
catch (IllegalArgumentException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
catch (IllegalStateException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

"mp" is a MediaPlayer obj.

If my question is incomplete tell me to complete.

thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this URL. It will help you.

http://blog.infidian.com/2008/04/04/tutorial-custom-media-streaming-for-androids-mediaplayer/